# Failed VSCode GitHub login setting token in crostini

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-chrome-os, crostini

I installed VSCode for Arm64 with Gnome-keyring installed on Crostini for Arm64 Chromebook (ASUS Chromebook Detachable CM3 CM3000) and tried to synchronize settings by GitHub account, but I get the following error.
When I exit VSCode, it logs me out of my GitHub account, and I have to log in again when I restart it.

```
2023-03-06 21:24:11.389 [info] Logging in for the following scopes: user:email
2023-03-06 21:24:11.444 [info] Trying without local server... (user:email)
2023-03-06 21:24:43.733 [info] Exchanging code for token...
2023-03-06 21:24:45.587 [info] Token exchange success!
2023-03-06 21:24:45.626 [info] Getting user info...
2023-03-06 21:24:46.364 [info] Got account info!
2023-03-06 21:24:46.376 [info] Storing 1 sessions...
2023-03-06 21:24:47.569 [info] Getting user info...
2023-03-06 21:24:47.620 [error] Setting token failed: Error: パス /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login のオブジェクトにインターフェース“org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection”がありません
2023-03-06 21:24:47.622 [info] Stored 1 sessions!
```

- VSCode version: 1.76.2

```
バージョン: 1.76.2
コミット: ee2b180d582a7f601fa6ecfdad8d9fd269ab1884
 日付: 2023-03-14T18:09:59.099Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Linux arm64 5.15.89-16172-g8db7d2810659
Sandboxed: No
```

- OS Version: ChromeOS 111.0.5563.71(Official Build)(32bit) Crostini Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) (Linux arm64 5.10.159-20950-g3963226d9eb4)

```
Linux penguin 5.15.89-16172-g8db7d2810659 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 6 18:42:56 PST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

What we know:

- Gnome-keyring is already installed.
- `~/.local/share/keyrings` already exists.
- [Looking at seahorse, it appears that no keyrings are stored at all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5ZC6.png)
- When I authenticated, I did not get a dialog to save the keyring password either.
- [I am also concerned that the URL handler icon stays out in the loading state (it does not disappear until the Chromebook itself is restarted).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OujXr.png)
- And I tried to make a password keyring with seahorse, but I can't.

```
No such secret collection at path: /
```

[trying make a password keyring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecICU.png)
[it failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSAJw.png)